# How to change the position of the ionic side menu button?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

HI i need to change the position of ionic side menu button in ionic sidemen app.i need to change the menu button forklift to right how can i do that?

Comment: Do you use Ionic template for side menu? Can you post template structure of your application? If you have menu.html file post code of that file. And also what you have implemented.

Comment: Thanks dude,i fixed that just need to replace right in left on side menu html

Comment: So post your answer, You also can do it using CSS and SASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a side menu defined as that :

```
<ion-side-menu side="right">
```

You can have it's button defined like that :

```
<a class="button button-icon button-clear fa fa-navicon fa-fw" ng-click="showMenu()">
</a>
```